# Will audio lag behind video when streaming over bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, lag, audio-streaming

I'm contemplating buying a bluetooth enabled speaker set for main use with my computer. What got me worried is **if there is any delay when sending audio over bluetooth?** For listening to music it should be fine, but even a small delay would make watching videos (or whatever else that requires video-audio sync) insufferable.

Comment: All media container formats interleave video and audio data. So there is no reason to worry. The only problem possible is stalling.

Comment: If you can get the video running in VLC you can correct any audio lag. Wouldn't work for things like Netflix though.

Comment: Have noticed this problem as well. When watching video on YouTube/Hulu, audio is out-of-sync. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @CharlesR I didn't go for a BT-set after all; way too much hassle. However, you could follow Tanner's advice and stream youtube videos etc thru VLC. Get that to work and syncing A/V won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I just bought a set of Bluetooth speakers and without special software (e.g., if everything is online like YouTube) the delay is very noticeable.